# Bootstrap 4 collapsed button not clickable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a website. I planned to have a collapsed menu but the collapsed button seems to be not working.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-grid.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.css"/>

</head>

<body>

<div class="pos-f-t">
<div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
<div class="bg-dark p-4">
  <h4 class="text-white">Title here.</h4>
  <span class="text-muted">Text here.</span>
</div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 </nav>
 </div>



 <!-- SCRIPT -->
 <script  src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script  src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
 <script  src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <!-- END OF SCRIPT -->
 </body>


 </html>
```

I copied this from the bootstrap site itself and moment I pasted it on my dreamweaver and loaded it, the bar was there as well as the collapsed button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is definitely with your **bootstrap dependency files**. Using CDN for js and css, page will easily work, or else to work offline, you should download the bootstrap files and **should place in correct order** and **import same in correct order** [Refer](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/).
You can try this (using Bootstrap CDN):

```html
<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-grid.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.css"/>  -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>

  <div class="pos-f-t">
    <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
      <div class="bg-dark p-4">
        <h4 class="text-white">Title here.</h4>
        <span class="text-muted">Text here.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
    </nav>
  </div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked!

Comment: @Anj You're welcome, anytime.

Answer (score 0):

try with `live link` of `css and script` or download library and put offline its worked.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-grid.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.css"/>-->



<body>

  <div class="pos-f-t">
    <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
      <div class="bg-dark p-4">
        <h4 class="text-white">Title here.</h4>
        <span class="text-muted">Text here.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
    </nav>
  </div>



  <!-- SCRIPT -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <!-- END OF SCRIPT -->
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the order of your javascript files are incorrect.

Also you don't need both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.bundle.js - just use the bundle as it is bootstrap.js + popper.js in 1 combined file (see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/contents/#js-files).

So... try changing your javascript to:

```
<!-- SCRIPT -->
<script  src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script  src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<!-- END OF SCRIPT -->
```

EDIT: It also looks like your css files are also in the wrong order & you don't need them all.. Change them to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-grid.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.css"/>

</head>

<body>

<div class="pos-f-t">
<div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
<div class="bg-dark p-4">
  <h4 class="text-white">Title here.</h4>
  <span class="text-muted">Text here.</span>
</div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 </nav>
 </div>



 <!-- SCRIPT -->
 <script  src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script  src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
 <script  src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <!-- END OF SCRIPT -->
 </body>


 </html>
```

You may missing some css or js files in project folder.